# Lower window with double click on title bar in xfce4

Tags: xfce

In the xfce4 window manager settings under Advanced I can choose a double-click action for the title bar, but `Lower` is not provided. So I tried the `xfce4-settings-editor > xfwm4 > double_click_action`, but neither of `lower` or `Lower` works.

Does anyone know for sure that this is not possible, or is there a way to get this working?

Comment: Since you ask this question, I guess you already know that **middle-click** on the title bar will lower the window in Xfce.

Comment: Now I sdcontarted to use Linux Mint+Cinnamon. It was trivial to configure it there.

Comment: So is the system which you want to configure this on Linux Mint?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your request, you must use the action: shade instead of lower to hide the window but still see the titlebar. If you want to hide the window, the action is iconify.

Comment: I neither want to shade nor to hide. The question is how to lower the window, the same as Settings->Window Manager->Keyboard->Lower Window.